# Getting microphone data (probably for c#)

Tags: c#, fft

i know there are many topics like mine, but i would realy love if somebody could explain me the theory behind the code.... what is the format of data you get from microphone?? Do same sounds return the same data from microphone or do you realy have to go through fft process if you want to compare sound samples.... Where can you save microphone data and analize it in live stream?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the open source [.NET Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) project which uses [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com). There is [an article on Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx) explaining how it works.